How to improve random write I/O for LMDB Java
Currently I have an application running on kubernetes with very low memory and using LMDB Java to store records in disk. During boot up time, I load all data into disk, with the following environment configurations:

No Metasync
No Sync
WriteMap
No Read Ahead

The application takes around 15 minutes to load, and I find that my disk is at its I/O max. Is there any configurations or changes I can make to help with this throughput to load my service faster.

My guess is that you probably can't improve if you do random writes.  It sounds like the random writes a resulting a bazzilion disk read and write operations on disk blocks scattered across the disk.  'Cos you are memory constrained, there is probably minimal memory for caching disk blocks in memory. IMO, the only solution is to change your application so that the file writes are sequential (or random but ordered).

Yeah ok I was making sure if there was any other things I could check. Just to give a better picture the total data size is around 1.5gb and there is about 100mb for page cache. But yes each write is a random write

Sounds right.  You are effectively thrashing the page cache.

@StephenC not sure if you know but do you think an LSM based store (rocksDB/levelDB) would be better suited for this load? Or irrespective of the underlying data store this task would be hard to get around without a long load time.

There is insufficient information to make a judgement.
